# Python 'in' function , pandas dataframe wrongly populated

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, dataframe

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import pandas as pd
import re

text = open("/Users/dynajose/Desktop/PlayList.rtf").read()
songDom = BeautifulSoup(text) 

data=defaultdict(list)
musicData=defaultdict(list)

f_music = songDom.find_all("div", {"class" : "_gx6 _agv"})

for music in f_music:
    try:
        Name_title = music.find("a","_gx7")
        data['Name'].append(Name_title.text)
    except:
        data['Name'].append("")

    try:
        type_title = music.find("div","_1fs8 fsm fwn fcg") 
        data['Type'].append(type_title.text)
    except:
        data['Type'].append("") 


for link_music in f_music:
    variable=link_music.find('a', href=re.compile('^https:'))['href']
    data['Link'].append(variable)


for verified_page in f_music:
    for page in verified_page:
        page_verified = page.find_all('span',{'aria-label':'Verified Page'})
        #print page_verified
        check= "Verified Page"
        for a in page_verified :
             if check in a :
                    musicData['Link'].append(True)
             else :
                    musicData['Link'].append(False)




#if sum([True for a in page_verified if check in a]) > 1:
         #   musicData['Link'].append(True)
        #else :
         #   musicData['Link'].append(False)


#df = pd.DataFrame(data)
dr= pd.DataFrame(musicData)
#df
dr
```

---

[image: Print page_verified output]

### [image: dr output]

Desired Result - 
So I want the DataFrame column to be True if the page is Verified. Wether a page is verified or not is defined by the span tag and aria-label tag. 
(DataFrame is Boolean)

My logic- 
I will append True if the row has "Verified page" in it.
else False.

But in this case all rows have "Verified Page" in it yet it goes to the else part.

Is there any function in Python that helps me do it more efficiently or any better way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Please post the actual text rather than an image of it, and also please post code that demonstrates the problem (the code doesn't define `f_music` so won't run). My *guess* is that you're trying to use the `in` on a container rather than a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `page_verified` variable is actually a list, that's why your check returns false.

Example :

```
l = ['ab']
'a' in l
False
```

If the list returned is always containing one element, just do

```
if check in page_verified[0]:
```

if the returned list can be multi elements, you can try something like (probably a better way to do it, but it'll work)

```
if sum([True for a in page_verified if check in a]) > 1:
```

** edit**

Please provide output of this so we can have more info

```
for music in f_music:
    for verified_page in f_music:
        for page in verified_page:
            page_verified = page.find_all('span',{'aria-label':'Verified Page'})
            print page_verified
            check= "Verified Page"
            print page_verified[0]
            print type(page_verified[0])
            print check in page_verified[0]
```

Comment: it returned me the same output.. check still returned false.

Comment: 49         print page_verified

     50         check= "Verified Page"

---> 51        print page_verified[0]

     52         print type(page_verified[0])

     53         print check in page_verified[0]


IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: converted a into str and now 'in' function works.. thank you @knighofni